# Limitar a um clique por pessoa

Tags: php, cookies

Eu quero limitar o clique de um botão a 1 clique por computador.
É possível?

Código até agora:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <br><br>
    <a style="color: grey; background-color: #fff; font-family: Arial; text-decoration: none; padding: 25px 50px; border-radius: 3px;" href="http://hugovales.esy.es/likeme/download_arquivo.php">I Like!</a>
    <br><br><br><a style="color: #fff; font-family: Arial;"><? include "contador_arquivo.txt"; ?> People Enjoy it</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sei que você disse "por computador", mas não seria o caso de ser "por usuário?". Neste caso bastaria você criar um cadastro/login e pronto***.

Answer (score 2):

Opa use esse javascript:

```
var createCookie = function(name, value, days) {
    var expires;
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
        c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start != -1) {
            c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
            c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
            if (c_end == -1) {
                c_end = document.cookie.length;
            }
            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end));
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Fornecido por: [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie)

Após isso você pode criar uma função no clique do link:

```
<a style="color: grey; background-color: #fff; font-family: Arial; text-decoration: none; padding: 25px 50px; border-radius: 3px;" href="http://hugovales.esy.es/likeme/download_arquivo.php" onclick=" return check()">I Like!</a>
```

depois criar uma função para validar:

```
function check(){
    check = getCookie('isclique');
    if(check){
       return false;
    }
    createCookie('isclique','true',100);
}
```

Algo do gênero. Fiz com pressa.
Mas essa validação não é 100%,  a "unica" maneira 100% que ainda da pra burlar mas é mais segura que essa, seria validar no backend.

Comment: Igual o @Guerra mencionou, essa validação não é 100% porque ela fica limitado ao `navegador`, caso o usuário trocar de navegador ele poderá novamente clicar.

Comment: Uma observação, aqui só funciona se você colocar `onclick="return check()"` ao invés de  `onclick="check()"`, que realmente faz mais sentido.

Comment: Eu não consegui. Em cada página coloco cada um dos códigos?